# Настройка прав доступа для gitlab-runner

Tags: linux, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

Пытаюсь запустить базвовый билд исользую gitlab-runner. Постоянно получаю `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/www/test_deploy’: Permission denied`.
Пользователя gitlab-runner добавил во все возможные группы. Подскажите, как решить эту проблема или в какую сторону смотреть!

Вот пример моего **config.toml**:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "Runner"
  url = "https://ссылка на гитлаб"
  token = "токен"
  executor = "shell"
  builds_dir = "/var/www/test_deploy/"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
    enabled = true
  [runners.docker]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

Работаю на **CentOS 7**. Вот группы, в которых состоит пользователь **gitlab-runner**.

```
root:x:0:gitlab-runner
wheel:x:10:gitlab-runner
tape:x:30:gitlab-runner
gitlab-runner:x:5008:
docker:x:982:gitlab-runner
```

Answer (score 0):

Если кому то вдруг поможет... Проблема была во владельце директории, поменяв его на **gitlab-runner** всё запустилось